# Data insert and Image Upload

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I'm trying to Insert some data from a Text Area in MySQL and Upload an image in a specific folder and save the image name in MySQL. But when i submit it only text area data (titulli , permbjajtja) gets inserted in database, the picture doesn't get uploaded and name of the picture is not inserted in MySQL.
Here is the form code:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="shtolajm1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="titulli"></textarea>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10"  name="permbajtja"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" style="margin-left:-5;"/> 
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;margin-top:10px;">Insert</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is the code that im using to insert the data to mysql and upload the picture:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    if (!strlen(trim($_POST['titulli']))==0 && !strlen(trim($_POST['permbajtja']))==0 )
    {
        $titulli=$_POST['titulli'];
        $permbajtja=$_POST['permbajtja'];
        $data=date('Y-m-d');
        $time=date('H:i');
        $username=$_SESSION['myusername'];
        $InsertQuerry="INSERT INTO lajme (titulli, permbajtja, data, ora, useri) VALUES ('$titulli','$permbajtja','$data','$time','$username')";
        if (mysql_query($InsertQuerry))
        {
            echo "Data inserted";

        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Type the title and container";
    }
}
$id_lajmi=mysql_insert_id();
if(isset($_FILES['files']['name']))
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) 
    {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];    
        if ($tmpFilePath != "")
        {    
           $path = "lajme_foto/";

           list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$id_lajmi."photo".$i.".".$ext)) 
           { 
                $emri_fotos=$path.$id_lajmi."photo".$i.".".$ext;
                $insertfoto="INSERT INTO lajme_foto (id_lajmi,emri_fotos) VALUES ('$id_lajmi','$emri_fotos')";
                if(mysql_query($insertfoto))
                {
                    echo "Image Inserted";
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: You're missing a valid enctype for your form.

Comment: It still doesnt work. I tryed, it shows me nothing when i submit the data.

Comment: Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Plus, you have an extra closing brace `}` at the end of your code that shouldn't be there; IF that is your actual code.

Comment: Also, is `session_start();` loaded? (since you're using sessions). I don't see it and this tells me that this isn't full code. No sense for me to put in an answer if I don't know what your full code is.

Comment: Session is OK everything just works fine, the         $InsertQuerry="INSERT INTO lajme (titulli, permbajtja, data, ora, useri) VALUES ('$titulli','$permbajtja','$data','$time','$username')";
works fine but when it comes to the photo UPLOAD it doenst do anythink not showing me an error or smth.

Comment: Plus, check for folder permission, it may not be letting you upload because it's unable to write to it. Also, did you try my suggestion about your extra `}`?

Comment: No it is right, because when i use the exact code on another page, it does Upload and save the photo name in MySQL.

Comment: If you're executing this from another sub-folder, then you may need to change your upload path. I.e.: `$path = "../lajme_foto/";` or depending on how many sub-folders you're in and where you're executing the code from. That may very well be the case here.

Comment: Do tell me what the problem was. Was it the path?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Your form tag should look like this:
`<form role="form" method="post" action="shtolajm1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: It still doesnt work. I tryed, it shows me nothing when i submit the data.

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST)` and look what the form sends you (the file is in $_FILES). If you have any doubts, post it here.